# Comment s'appelle le phénomène de la présence des mots d'origine d'une autre langue dans un livre rédigé en français?

Tags: vocabulaire, littérature, allemand

Par exemple dans le roman *Le rois des aulnes*, on constate l'utilisation d'un grand nombre de mots allemands, y compris :

1. des noms propres (surtout les anthroponymies et les toponymes),
2. des emprunts à l'allemand (ceux qui font déjà partie du lexique français),
3. des noms qui ont certes des équivalences en français mais qui sont laissés tels quels par l'auteur, pour créer une certaine ambiance exotique.

Est-ce que le terme « germanisme » convient à définir ces trois types de phénomènes ?

Exemple :

> En 1936, le **Feldmarschall** **Hermann Göring** qui avait la haute
>   main sur **Rominten** au double titre de président du gouvernement de
>   Prusse et de grand veneur du **Reich** – **Reichsjägermeister** – avait
>   fait construire à proximité son propre pavillon de chasse, le
>   **Jägerhof**, qui sous son apparence de stricte rusticité écrasait par ses
>   raffinements le faste naïf du **Jagdhaus** impérial.(Michel Tournier)

De plus, pour généraliser les choses, comment nommer le phénomène de la présence des mots et des tournures étrangères à la langue dans laquelle un texte est rédigé ?

Comment: C'est un livre redige en francais, mais qui se passe ou bien en allemagne ou largement an Alsace, une region bilingue par definition.  De s'emballer avec l'etiquette de germanisme, qui a un relent de snobisme et d'exageration, semble un peu deplace vu les circonstances..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La règle générale, je crois, est ainsi: si la définition n'est pas donnée dans le texte ou que le mot n'est pas d'abord mis à part (comme *Reichsjägermeister*), on ne parlera pas encore de germanisme. Si le mot est rentré dans l'usage courant de sorte à ce que l'on n'aie plus besoin d'en donner la définition (Reich), il s'agit d'un germanisme. Si l'emprunt est ancien et que le sens en français a glissé (p.ex. chenapan, de *Schnapphahn*, « voleur de grand chemin », XVIe siècle), la saveur germanique peut être considérée atténuée, on l'appellera alors « germanisme » ou non, au choix.

L'Académie [donne la définition](http://www.la-definition.fr/definition/germanisme) de *germanisme*:

> Construction, tournure, vocable propres à la langue allemande ou transposés de la langue allemande dans une autre langue.

On notera que si l'on prend cette définition à la lettre, ce qui est parfaitement justifiable, tous vos exemples sont des germanismes.

Par contre, si j'avais à donner mon avis, les noms propres en général (Rominten) ne sont pas des germanismes, qu'ils soient écrits comme endonymes (exactement comme dans la langue originale, p. ex. Göring) ou exonymes (adaptés par la langue d'accueil, comme Goering, quoi que dans ce cas, la règle pour se débarasser de l'accent en le remplaçant par un e provient elle-même de l'allemand). On pourrait néanmoins parler de germanisme si, malgré l'existence d'une variante couramment admise en français (Dresde, Cologne, Aix-la-Chapelle, Strasbourg), l'on utilisait la variante allemande (Dresden, Köln, Aachen, Straßburg).

Les mots d'origine allemande, facilement reconnaissables comme tels et faisant déjà partie du lexique français sont toujours des germanismes: Reich, Feldmarschall. Ce dernier est utilisé un français [depuis le milieu du XVIIIe siècle](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feld-mar%C3%A9chal%2CFeldmarschall&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfeld%20-%20mar%C3%A9chal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CFeldmarschall%3B%2Cc0), le plus souvent sous la variante de feld-maréchal.

En ce qui concerne les mots écrits comme en allemand par exotisme (*Jägerhof*), encore une fois suivant la définition de l'Académie, sont des germanismes. Par contre, en pratique je crois que l'on ne parlerait pas d'emprunt ou de germanisme tant que la définition est donnée dans chaque texte qui en fait l'emploi.

Comment: C'est bien clair et détaillé, merci~!